# i cant receive decibels with PyUSB at RarsberryPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyusb, thonny

I have a Sound Meter ([SLM-25](https://www.skroutz.gr/s/25917347/%CE%97%CF%87%CF%8C%CE%BC%CE%B5%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF-%CE%A8%CE%B7%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BA%CF%8C-30-130dB-SLM-25.html)), that i want to receive the data of producing sound (decibels) using Python to a RaspberryPi.

I have already connect via USB the Sound Meter with RaspberryPi and receive the main infos of the device, but i cant receive the data of the sounds (decibels) that the device tracks.

In particular i have used the following script but i failed when i tried to use: ctrl_transfer of [PyUSB](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#talk-to-me-honey).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import usb.core
import requests
import time

dev=usb.core.find(idVendor=0x10C4,idProduct=0x82CD)
print (dev)
```

and the result is:

```
DEVICE ID 10c4:82cd on Bus 001 Address 005 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x110 USB 1.1
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x10c4
 idProduct              : 0x82cd
 bcdDevice              :    0x0 Device 0.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Error Accessing String
 iProduct               :    0x2 Error Accessing String
 iSerialNumber          :    0x0 
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 64 mA ===================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x29 (41 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0x80 Bus Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x20 (64 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Human Interface Device ====================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x3 Human Interface Device
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
      ENDPOINT 0x1: Interrupt OUT ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x1 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
```

I tried the following (with many combinations), but i failed to get data:

```
for bRequest in range(255):
    try:
        ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, bRequest, 0, 0, 2)
        print (ret)
```

What i have to do to receive the data of the decibel meter ?

Comment: If there is no documentation by the manufacturer or a Linux driver you first have to reverse engineer the protocol spoken on USB level. Use an OS and application the sound meter supports and record the USB traffic e.g. using Wireshark or a different USB sniffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Robert. I think that the software run at windows. Although, I will try to record the USB traffic with Wireshark and I will update the post.